# Mixed type graph in JUNG, does not show arrows when graph is filtered with a vertex predicate

Tags: jung2

I have a mixed type graph (SparseMultiGraph) in JUNG and and have managed to get edge arrows on my edges by adding the show edge arrows preicate, but when the I filter the graph (to only show a subportion) first using a VertexPredicateFilter the arrows are lost, how do I get them back?

my predicate to show edges arrows looks like

```
public class ShowEdgeArrowsPredicate<T1, T2> implements
        Predicate<Context<Graph<String, Tuple>, Tuple>> {

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Context<Graph<String, Tuple>, Tuple> context) {
        Graph<String, Tuple> graph = context.graph;
        return graph.getEdgeType(context.element) == EdgeType.DIRECTED;
    }

}
```

and I add this to the renderer like:

```
vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeArrowPredicate(new ShowEdgeArrowsPredicate<String, Tuple>());
```

but I don't see where I specify which end must have its arrow painted.

I've been trying to follow...

http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/jung-samples/xref/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/PluggableRendererDemo.html